# Autoprefixer: Sourcemap is generated but it isn't working?

Tags: sass, gruntjs, source-maps

I am just starting to use Autoprefixer in my coding process. I am using grunt-autoprefixer for it. https://github.com/nDmitry/grunt-autoprefixer

**In my gruntfile.js**

```
 sass: {
    dist: {
        options: {
            sourcemap: true
    },
    files:{
        'css/style.css': 'sass/style.scss'
    }
  }
},

autoprefixer: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      map: true
    },
    files:{
      'build/style.css': 'css/style.css'
    }
  }
},
```

### The sourcemap gets generated. However when I view it in Chrome, it is still showing .css instead of .scss?

Here are the sourcemaps.
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B-PvLw2M9kBZZmRkMk9tekh6QWc&usp=sharing

---

[image: Screenshot of files architecture]

Comment: Show your source maps please (both).

Comment: Here is the sourcemaps. Thanks. You should be able to access it. https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B-PvLw2M9kBZZmRkMk9tekh6QWc&usp=sharing

Comment: @IlanFrumer Yeap. It is not. But Dimitry has pointed out that sourcemaps are necessary for him to troubleshoot it. He is the creator of grunt-autoprefixer so he will know how.

Comment: the map looks ok, paths are right. At the bottom of `build/style.css` should be the comment `/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */`. If there is a server that serve static files, ensure that it serve the `build` directory too. Also check if your browser support source maps and the feature is enabled: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger#Use_a_source_map or (Chrome) Dev Tools -> Settings -> Enable source maps

Comment: @DmitryNikitenko Thanks for the help. The bottom of build/style.css is indeed /*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */ and my files are really simple. Just HTML + CSS. I am making a small css experiment. My browser has support for source map and the feature has been turned on. If in my HTML file, I change build/style.css to css/style.css I will get the sourcemap (I will see .scss), it is using the SASS's sourcemap. So not sure why Autoprefixer's sourcemap can't work.

Comment: @DmitryNikitenko I just tried the very same code on another machine, I manage to get the sourcemap working without any tweaking. Weird. Might be some cache, chrome's workspace? or whatever settings that is throwing me off.

Answer (score 0):

I have identified that the problem is because of Google Drive.
I am hosting all my code on Google Drive and do my coding straight onto it.

There is some caching and syncing problem.
So in terms of setup, everything is correct.